# Can't Change Permission in Mounted Drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, mount, samba

Hello im new using Ubuntu.

I try to change permission from directory in mounted drive but always back to root or user while run command 'chmod'.

i already try this command :

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o username=user,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sda1 /media/user/Disk
```

with this command It was successful but failed again and I don't know why. oh fyi I used a drive from a previous Windows Server operating system. so maybe the type here is NTFS. And now im using Ubuntu 22.04.

So what should I add or change in my command? Or am I working on something that has nothing to do with the problem I have? If yes, can you tell me a possible way to change the permissions with chmod or chown if necessary. Of course, access is set to 770 (drwxrwx---) to all directories on the drive. Sorry if my English isn't very good.

Answer (score 0):

As NTFS is a Windows file system, it does not support Unix permissions. mount plays around this by mounting it with a static "permission mask". You could change that to change the permissions for the whole mounted drive.

Rewriting your command, that would make
`sudo mount -t ntfs -o username=user,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,mode=777 /dev/sda1 /mnt/drive`

Notice the mount point: /media is for automatic udisks mounts, not for manual ones. You'd probably have to manually create it with `sudo mkdir -p /mnt/drive`

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. @Savchenko

I Already try your answer but no change. Humm maybe my mistake not given full detail. File System Type drive after mounted is **fuseblk**. i dont know how to solve this problem. 

I already create a static point mount like your answer in `/mnt/drive` and using `mode=777` in command mount.

Comment: The probem is unsolvable. The entire mounted drive is always owned by the uid stated in the `mount` command. NTFS literally has nowhere in the file system of that drive to store any owner or permission details, even though you give full directory write permissions.